# Interleave 2 linked lists C++

Tags: c++

I was working on a function that interweaves 2 singly linked lists together for a course (I already finished the lab, just working on it on my own time now) and I'm stuck. I've tried a bunch of stuff, but I can't really figure it out. Can anyone help me out? thanks!

```
 /**
 * Create a new linked_list by merging two existing linked_lists.
 * PRE: list1 is the first Node in a linked_list (if NULL, then it is empty)
 * PRE: list2 is the first Node in another linked_list (if NULL, then it is empty)
 * POST: A new linked_list is returned that contains new Nodes with the keys from
 * the Nodes in list1 and list2, starting with the key of the first Node of list1,
 * then the key of the first Node of list2, etc.
 * When one list is exhausted, the remaining keys come from the other list.
 * For example: [1, 2] and [3, 4, 5] would return [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
 */
Node* interleave(Node* list1, Node* list2){
  if (list1 == NULL && list2 == NULL) { return NULL; }

  Node * p1 = list1;
  Node * p2 = list2;
  Node * newNode = new Node;

  while (list1 != NULL && list2 != NULL) {
    newNode->key = p1->key;
    p1 = p1->next;
    newNode->next->key = p2->key;
    p2 = p2->next;
  }

  if (list1 == NULL && list2 != NULL) {
    while (list2 != NULL) {
      newNode->key = p2->key;
      p2 = p2->next;
    }
  } else if (list2 == NULL && list1 != NULL) {
    while (list1 != NULL) {
      newNode->key = p1->key;
      p1 = p1->next;
    }
  }
  return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Your first `while` loop should run forever because if `list1` is initially non-null, then it will never be changed to null in the loop.  Or if `list1` is initially null, then `list2` is not null, and it would never be changed to null in the loop.

Comment: On the first line, you already check the initial value of `list1` and `list2`.  I think that first `while` condition should instead check whether or not `p1` and `p2` are null.  The other `while` loops would also have similar changes.

Comment: Also, you only create one `newNode`, and you keep assigning new values to that single node.  It looks like you want to update the `while` loops to also create an additional new `Node` and set `newNode` to point to it after the current `newNode` has been properly set up.

Comment: Thank you! I initially made new Nodes with each iteration, but wasn't sure if that was right so I tried this first. I will try that!

Comment: See [interleave 2 linked list C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131009/interleave-2-linked-list-c)